# Moving project tomcat to jboss getting error

Tags: java, jboss, tomcat7

I am building a project with JSF and Spring. My project working nice in tomcat 7. But when I am trying to deploy my project on Jboss, I am getting an error ::
         java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy

Can anyone please tell me what are the changes I need to do if I moved into JBoss. I am using netbeans IDE.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

two result you might find interesting:

- https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBREFLECT-137?focusedCommentId=12542909&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-12542909
- https://community.jboss.org/message/736634#736634

So it is a deployment issue i believe. Hope this helps!

Comment: I have already seen this link. but could not make my solution.

Comment: So you say none of the given deployment issues can occur in your case (which were mentioned in the bottom comments in the given link)?

Comment: Actually I didn't understand what they wants to tell.